# adduser fails when relating hadoop-plugin to hbase-master

Tags: juju, hadoop

I'm trying to set up Hbase in juju using the following charm: https://jujucharms.com/u/bigdata-dev/apache-hbase/trusty/19
I receive an error when I try to add a relation between the hadoop-plugin and hbase-master.

Output from juju status:

```
hbase-master:
charm: cs:~bigdata-dev/trusty/apache-hbase-19
exposed: false
service-status:
  current: blocked
  message: Waiting for relation to apache-hadoop-plugin and apache-zookeeper
  since: 28 Feb 2016 05:01:52-08:00
relations:
  hadoop-plugin:
  - plugin
units:
  apache-hbase/0:
    workload-status:
      current: blocked
      message: Waiting for relation to apache-hadoop-plugin and apache-zookeeper
      since: 28 Feb 2016 05:01:52-08:00
    agent-status:
      current: idle
      since: 28 Feb 2016 05:46:55-08:00
      version: 1.25.3.1
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.25.3.1
    machine: "6"
    public-address: 10.0.3.35
    subordinates:
      plugin/0:
        workload-status:
          current: error
          message: 'hook failed: "install"'
          since: 28 Feb 2016 05:23:41-08:00
        agent-status:
          current: idle
          since: 28 Feb 2016 05:23:41-08:00
          version: 1.25.3.1
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "install"'
        agent-version: 1.25.3.1
        upgrading-from: cs:trusty/apache-hadoop-plugin-10
        public-address: 10.0.3.35
```

Checking the logs for the plugin/0:

```
    Creating user hdfs in primary group hadoop and secondary groups []
INFO install Traceback (most recent call last):
INFO install   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-plugin-/charm/hooks/install", line 17, in <module>
INFO install     common.manage()
INFO install   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-plugin-/charm/hooks/common.py", line 123, in manage
INFO install     manager.manage()
INFO install   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-plugin-0/charm/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/charmhelpers/core/charmframework/base.py", line 115, in manage
INFO install     self.run_callbacks()
INFO install   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-plugin-0/charm/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/charmhelpers/core/charmframework/base.py", line 159, in run_callbacks
INFO install     self.fire_event('callbacks', component)
2016-02-28 13:23:41 INFO install   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-plugin-0/charm/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/charmhelpers/core/charmframework/base.py", line 189, in fire_event
INFO install     callback()
INFO install   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-plugin-0/charm/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jujubigdata/handlers.py", line 101, in install
INFO install     self.dist_config.add_users()
INFO install   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-plugin-0/charm/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jujubigdata/utils.py", line 149, in add_users
INFO install     host.adduser(username, primary_group=primary_grp, secondary_groups=secondary_grps)
INFO install TypeError: adduser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'primary_group'
ERROR juju.worker.uniter.operation runhook.go:107 hook "install" failed: exit status 1
```

The code where it fails:

```
def add_users(self):
    for group in self.groups:
        host.add_group(group)
    for username, details in self.users.items():
        primary_grp = None
        secondary_grps = None
        groups = details.get('groups', [])
        if groups:
            primary_grp = groups[0]
            secondary_grps = groups[1:]
        hookenv.log('Creating user {0} in primary group {1} and secondary groups {2}'
                    .format(username, primary_grp, secondary_grps))
        host.adduser(username, primary_group=primary_grp, secondary_groups=secondary_grps)
```

Any idea how I can get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by changing

```
host.adduser(username, primary_group=primary_grp, secondary_groups=secondary_grps)
```

to

```
host.adduser(username, group=primary_grp, groups=secondary_grps)
```

and then retry the service with

```
juju resolved --retry servicename
```

Comment: The bigdata team is fixing this charm, in the future though, mixing the `bigdata-dev` charms with the released charms might result in breakage. If you have a specific need to do this I'd reach out to the team and see how they can help you: bigdata@lists.ubuntu.com